Issues with Motion Planning Path on UR Robot Using MoveIt API Tutorial
I'm following the MoveIt2 Motion Planning API Tutorial on ROS Humble with a self-compiled version of MoveIt2. The original tutorial works well on the Panda robot and generates smooth, efficient paths. However, when I adapt the code for my UR robot, the motion planning produces excessively twisted and inefficient paths (see attached images for comparison).
Here are some details of my setup:

ROS Version: Humble
MoveIt2 Version: Self-compiled
Robot Model: UR (replacing the Panda in the tutorial)
Planners Tested: I tried
multiple planners, and all resulted in similarly inefficient paths.
Joint Limits: I haven’t set any joint limits in the configuration for either robots.

Does anyone know why this difference occurs or have any advice on how to achieve similar smooth paths with the UR robot? Any guidance on potential adjustments in the MoveIt configuration or UR-specific settings would be appreciated!
Thank you!


Even with 40 steps interpolation, the UR robot still tends to take a large, inefficient path between these small changes in pose.

The panda robot occasionally takes a longer route for the same target pose as well.



is there a reliable way to consistently get the UR robot to take the shortest path?

Getting this behavior depends on the planner you choose and how much time you give it to search. As you have discovered, the RRTstar planner implementation does not optimize for this metric. The fact that the second "R" in RRT means "Random" hints at this.
I've wanted this too, but have not found an open source moveit planner with this feature. I suspect that many users pre-provision waypoints rather than letting the planner have complete freedom of choice.

The Panda has seven degrees of freedom so it can execute motions the UR can't.
Check to make sure the UR isn't hitting joint limits along the way, and experiment with the orientation of the end-effector pose to see if you can ever get it to take a short path to that pose.
Unfortunately a couple of nearby task-space end-effector poses can be strangely connected or even disconnected in the joint space that the robot moves in.
You might try a linear position interpolation and orientation SLERP between the start and target poses to generate some other candidate targets, and see if MoveIt can plan a "short path" for some of the intermediate poses closer to the start pose. Seeing where it breaks down could be useful.

Thank you so much for your insightful answer—it has been really helpful! I tried using interpolation to break down the single target path into 40 small steps. Each interpolated pose has only minimal differences from the last, yet the UR robot still tends to take a large, inefficient path between these small changes in position. On rare occasions, it does find a shorter path, which confirms that a shorter path is indeed feasible in the joint space.

I understand that motion planning can yield multiple valid solutions, so I'm wondering: is there a reliable way to consistently get the UR robot to take the shortest path? Should I consider running multiple planning attempts and selecting the shortest one? Or would using a more advanced planner help here? (I'm currently using RRTstar.)

I also tried similar setups with the Panda robot and noticed that, for the same target pose, it usually finds shorter paths, though it occasionally takes a longer route as well. In contrast, the UR robot mostly takes the longer route, with only a few instances of the shorter path. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you again!

@Liu11loveslearning I've had similar encounters with the UR, where a path was planned, usually going through a table and I fixed it by moving the start pose further away from joint limits. This worked for a pick-place application, when trying to pick objects close to the base_link, moving the end effector further (intermediate-pose) out helped a lot with successful plans. Before that I also tried multiple planning attempts, but the results were inconsistent and based on a predefined waypoint limit, which was use-case specific. I recommend trying both, but the first option worked best for me!
